# How to Find All possible paths between 2 vertices

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am debugging a legacy code where a road network has been represented by `Boost Graph`.
The `A_Star` search doesn't give me the shortest path between 2 certain points and I know `boost` can't be wrong (not until I have debugged my code a thousand times).

To debug manually, I need to know how I can print **all possible paths between 2 vertices**. In my output, each path should be represented by a series of edges and their corresponding weights.

I value your kind help and comments

Comment: In a DAG, breadth-first search. If it's undirected or there's a cycle, there could be an infinite amount of paths. But still, breadth-first search.

Comment: Also, check your heuristic on A*... it's probably invalid.

Comment: @Barry thanks for both the hints. I will go check it out. I am sure I will be back with more requests for hints :)

Comment: A related problem describing the complexity is [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/how-hard-is-counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-directed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A* is based on an heuristic. If the legacy uses A* it means the problem is more complex then just find the shortest path.

To find the shortest path between 2 vertices, there are certain Graph Algorithms, Dijkstra is the easyest one to implement (make sure to make it with loop checking as well). These are deterministic.

If you need to know ALL paths between 2 vertices, this one is NP complete , meaning you need to go with backtracking.

A* is generally used to solve NP complete problems. The results isn't THE BEST path, is just ONE VERY GOOD PATH FOUND IN DECENT TIME .

The heuristic from A* is used to drop recursions or transform the algorithm from a backtracking to a Breadth-first-search (usually the latter).

An example of difference between an problem solvable by A* algorithm and a Dijkstra would  be as following (from the top of my head ) :

- Find the shortest roads in Manhatan from Corner X,Y to corner X1,Y1  (solvable by Dijkstra or in case of Manhatan BFS)
- Pick the best route in Manhatan from Corner X,Y to corner X1,Y1 considering traffic and traffic lights , according to certain hours (so it's a significant difference between the cost for edge 1,1 to 1,2 if you arrive at 1,1 at t0 and if you arrive at 1,1 at t1 > t0, example : that portion of the road gets blocked at t1 for 10 hours ).